# How to move to an existing UIViewController (in storyboard) with code in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I know how to do it with buttons by clicking and dragging, but I have a situation where I need a transition without a button.  so what code will allow me to transition from the current UIViewController to a different UIViewController that is already initialized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you will need to create the segue in the storyboard and give a proper name to the identifier of this segue. You can do this by clicking on the segue (left panel) and then click on Attributes (right panel).

[image]

The same way you can call this segue using buttons or selection of table rows from your storyboard, you can call it from code using `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:`

As when using the button and cells on uitableview, your view controller call `prepareForSegue:` You override this method in your view if you need to pass any data between controllers:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue?, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue!.identifier == "MySegue" {
            let viewController:ViewController = segue!.destinationViewController as ViewController
            viewController.receiveSomedata = self.sendSomeData
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Drag a segue from viewController to viewController

[image]

2. Set identifier for this segue

[image]

3. When you want to go to next viewController

   ```
     self.performSegueWithIdentifier("yoursegue", sender: nil)
   ```